# Simple Linq query that joins two tables and returns a collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables LookUpCodes and LookUpValues they are defined as below:

```
public partial class LookUpCodes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? CodeId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}



public partial class LookUpValues
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CodeId { get; set; }
    public string CodeValue { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Each LookUpCode can have multiple Values associated with it. I want to pass in a code and get associated list of values back.

This is probably a common question as I have seen this everywhere, I am not looking for an answer per se, if someone can just explain how to build the proper query I would be obliged.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
public IEnumerable<LookUpValues> GetValuesByCode(string cd)
{
    var query = from code in _context.LookUpCodes
                join values in _context.LookUpValues on code.CodeId equals values.CodeId
                where code.Code == cd
                select new { LookUpValues = values };
    return (IEnumerable<LookUpValues>) query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close to that you are looking for:

```
public IEnumerable<LookUpValues> GetValuesByCode(string cd)
{
    var query = from code in _context.LookUpCodes
                join values in _context.LookUpValues 
                on code.CodeId equals values.CodeId
                where code.Code == cd
                select values;

    return query;
}
```

Since you have written the `join`, I assume that you have understood how it works. However let's revisit it:

```
from a in listA
join b in listB
on a.commonId equals b.commonId
```

In the above snippet we join the contents of `listA` with the contents of `listB` and we base their `join` on a `commonId` property existing in items of both lists. Apparently the pair of `a` and `b` that fulfill the `join` criterion it would form one of the possible many results.

Then the `where` clause is applied on the results of the `join. The joined items that pass the`where`filter is the new result. Even at this point the results is still pairs of`a`and`b`.

Last you project, using the `select` keyword each pair of the results to a new object. In your case, for each pair of `code` and `values` that passed also the `where` filter, you return only the `values`.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response and, the really good explanation. I have another question, how can I order the values by descending order of the CodeValue property ?

Comment: You are welcome. You can achieve this as simple as you already described it. Just before the select statement place this `orderby values descending `

Comment: Thank you for the education. I hope this helps others as well.